# Ground state of an harmonic chain and Klein-Gordon vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, harmonic-oscillator, second-quantization, klein-gordon-equation

Consider the lagrangian of a system of classical coupled harmonic oscillators of mass $M$, connected with springs with elastic constant $\chi$ and connected to the background with springs of elastic constant $\Psi$. The Lagrangian for a one dimensional system then reads
\begin{equation}\label{eq:CSHOLagrangian}
    L=\sum_{\alpha=-N}^{N}\frac{1}{2}M\dot{\eta}^2_\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\chi(\eta_{\alpha+1}-\eta_{\alpha})^2-\frac{1}{2}\Psi\eta_{\alpha}^2
\end{equation}
This Lagrangian is identical to the discretized Lagrangian of the Klein-Gordon field.
By calling $R=\Psi/\chi$ It can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{\alpha=-N}^{N}\frac{1}{2}M\dot{\eta}^2-\frac{1}{2}\chi\left[(1+R)\eta_{\alpha}^2-2\eta_{\alpha+1}\eta_{\alpha}+\eta_{\alpha+1}^2\right]
\end{equation}

Then by defining the vector $\boldsymbol{\eta}=(\eta_{-N},...,\eta_{N})$ we can write the lagrangian as
\begin{equation}\label{eq:HCLMatrix}
    L=\frac{1}{2}M\dot{\boldsymbol{\eta}}^T\boldsymbol{I}\dot{\boldsymbol{\eta}}-\frac{1}{2}\chi \boldsymbol{\eta}^T\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{\eta}
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{I}$ denotes the identity matrix and $\boldsymbol{C}$ is the adimensional coupling matrix.

We now consider the Hamiltonian of the system of oscillators and diagonalize it. Let $\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{U}\boldsymbol{\eta}$, where $\boldsymbol{U}$ is the orthonormal matrix that brings $\boldsymbol{C}$ into the diagonal matrix $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}$. With this transformation, the diagonalized Hamiltonian reads
\begin{equation}\label{eq:HCHamiltonian}
    \begin{aligned}
        H&=\frac{1}{2}M\dot{\boldsymbol{y}}^T\boldsymbol{I}\dot{\boldsymbol{y}}+\frac{1}{2}\chi \boldsymbol{y}^T\boldsymbol{\Gamma}\boldsymbol{y}=\\
        &=\sum_{\alpha=0}^{N}\frac{1}{2}M\dot{y}_{\alpha}^2+\frac{1}{2}\chi\Gamma_{\alpha} y_{\alpha}^2.
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

We now interpret this Hamiltonian quantum mechanically with the appropriate substitutions.
The eigenvalue equation for the Hamiltonian, in position space, is then given by
\begin{equation}
    \left[\sum_{\alpha=0}^{N}\frac{\hat{p}_\alpha^2}{2M}+\frac{1}{2}M\omega_\alpha^2\hat{y}_{\alpha}^2\right]\Psi=E\Psi,
\end{equation}
where $\omega_\alpha^2=\chi\Gamma_{\alpha}/M$. Since the Hamiltonian in this form represents a system of non interacting harmonic oscillators, it is separable as $\sum_{\alpha} \hat{h}_\alpha$.
It is then straightforward to compute the ground state of the system, which is given by
\begin{equation}
\Psi=\left(\frac{M}{\pi \hbar}\right)^{\frac{2N}{4}}\mathrm{Det}(\boldsymbol{\omega})^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{M}{2\hbar}\boldsymbol{y}^T\boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{y}}
\end{equation}
where we have introduced the diagonal matrix $\boldsymbol{\omega}$, which has $\omega_\alpha$ as eigenvalues.

I was wondering: if we now perform the continuum limit, do we obtain the KG vacuum?
By the KG vacuum I mean the vacuum that can be computed after second quantizing the KG field.

Another way to phrase my question (in more general terms) is: is it equivalent to first perform the continuum limit on the initial Lagrangian and then canonically quantize the field, as opposed to first quantizing the discretized field and then performing the continuum limit?